# Auto populating Case fields from User

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to populate fields in side my `Case` Object (`RSM,ISR,FAE1`).  So what I thought about doing was get all of the `CreatedById's` from `Case`, and then go through my `User` object and pull out their RSMs, ISRs, and FAEs.  I realized this is Extremely inefficient, but I can't think of any other way. Posted below is my current solution, but doesn't work properly and I get a null pointer exception.  I noticed the inefficiency through my debug logs.  This seems like it should be a simple process.. but what am I missing?

```
if(Trigger.isBefore || Trigger.isAfter){
Set<id> caseIdSet = new Set<id>();
 //Getting a set of case IDs, 
 for (Case c: [Select id,FAE__c,ISR__c,RSM__c,CreatedById from Case])  
  {
        caseIdSet.add(c.CreatedById); 
         system.debug('This is caseIdSet  ' + caseIdSet + '\n');              
  }   

Map < id, User > userList = new Map < Id, User > ([SELECT id,FAE1__c,ISR__c, RSM__c FROM User where CreatedById IN: caseIdSet]);  
system.debug('THIS IS THE USER LIST   ' +userList);      
for (Case c: trigger.new)
  {
   if(userList.isEmpty()){     
   break;
   }
   else  if (userList.get(c.CreatedById).FAE1__c != null || userList.get(c.CreatedById).FAE1__c != '') 
   {
       system.debug('Inside FAE1 Condition ');
        c.FAE__c = userList.get(c.CreatedById).FAE1__c;                 
   }
  else  if(userList.get(c.CreatedById).ISR__c != null || userList.get(c.CreatedById).ISR__c != '')
   {           
          system.debug('Inside ISR Condition ');
        c.ISR__c = userList.get(c.CreatedById).ISR__c;   
   }
  else  if(userList.get(c.CreatedById).RSM__c != null || userList.get(c.CreatedById).RSM__c != '') 
   {         
         system.debug('Inside RSM Condition '); 
        c.RSM__c = userList.get(c.CreatedById).RSM__c;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a stab at changing your code. See the differences and let me know how it goes. (Note: I did not compile or test it, so it may need some massaging.

Most significantly, Trigger.new does not always exist. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm

```
if(Trigger. isExecuting){ // changed to check if we are in a trigger. 

if(Trigger.New == null){ // exit if we have no Trigger.new (such as delete trigger)
    break;
}

Set<Id> caseIdSet = new Set<Id>();
 //Getting a set of case IDs, 
 for (Case c: [SELECT Id, FAE__c, ISR__c, RSM__c, CreatedById FROM Case])  
  {
        caseIdSet.add(c.CreatedById); 
        //system.debug('This is caseIdSet  ' + caseIdSet + '\n');              
  }   

Map < Id, User > userList = new Map < Id, User > ([SELECT id, FAE1__c, ISR__c, RSM__c FROM User WHERE CreatedById IN :caseIdSet]);  
//system.debug('THIS IS THE USER LIST   ' +userList);      
for (Case c: trigger.new) //NOTE: This will fail if it is a "delete" trigger and is likely the source of your problems
  {
   if(userList.isEmpty()){     
   break;
   }
if(userList.containsKey(c.CreatedById){
   if (userList.get(c.CreatedById).FAE1__c != null || String.isNotEmpty(userList.get(c.CreatedById).FAE1__c) ) 
   {
       system.debug('Inside FAE1 Condition ');
        c.FAE__c = userList.get(c.CreatedById).FAE1__c;                 
   }
  else if(userList.get(c.CreatedById).ISR__c != null || String.isNotEmpty(userList.get(c.CreatedById).ISR__c))
   {           
          system.debug('Inside ISR Condition ');
        c.ISR__c = userList.get(c.CreatedById).ISR__c;   
   }
  else if(userList.get(c.CreatedById).RSM__c != null || String.isNotEmpty(userList.get(c.CreatedById).RSM__c )) 
   {         
         system.debug('Inside RSM Condition '); 
        c.RSM__c = userList.get(c.CreatedById).RSM__c; 
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi David, So i'm getting an error at if(Trigger.New == null){ // exit if we have no Trigger.new (such as delete trigger)
    break;
}  "Loop control must be contained in a loop"

Answer (score 1):

So from the creator of the case, you want to get the creator of the User? I don't think that's what you want to do. You should query the creator itself. that's your problem. Change your query :

```
    Map < id, User > userList = new Map < Id, User > ([
               SELECT id,FAE1__c,ISR__c, RSM__c FROM User where Id IN: caseIdSet]);
```